# Programmatically creating cordova/ionic apps

Tags: java, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a development environment where web apps can be hosted. We generally use angular for our web apps so ionic should already be a pretty close match.

What I'm looking for is a way to be able to take a web application in angular and basically "generate" the ionic app out of it. We can assume that the app has been "modified" to correctly import the ionic module(s) and the necessary code.

Other than that, the site *must* remain functional on a desktop client (but I assume this is not an issue) and we want to "generate" the apk (or whatever target environment is required) based on the original web app.

Ideally the generation should be triggered by basically right clicking in a menu and selecting "Generate APK". This means I'm looking for programmatic access to whatever API cordova/ionic has.

My google-fu is letting me down though because all I can find though is command line references, I would prefer to stay away from commandline-level integration unless absolutely required. Other than that any search for API just brings up the javascript API they expose, not any API they might expose to programmatically generate artifacts like an APK.

**UPDATE**: I don't mind a downvote (the question is rather hard to phrase correctly) but at least state why so I can improve upon it.

Comment: Upvoted, I think the question is reasonably phrased. Some people don't understand the question and blame the author.

Answer (score 1):

Building a native APK in command line should be possible using the Android Gradle toolchain. You can go thru the process in the IDE and then just replace the files for your created app with the newly generated files and invoke gradle. For other OS's this becomes harder e.g. for iOS using xcodebuild is pretty hairy and if you add into it complexities like hosting Macs in the cloud (required for xcode) and the changes Apple makes all the time...

We implemented pretty much that (and a lot more) for Java at [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/), we also support including [Cordova plugins](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/phonegap-cordova-compatibility-for-codename-one.html) which might work for you. We also provide white label services for 3rd parties.